# Is the ubuntu OS the same version across Phones, Tablets, and PCs?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, phone

As I am sure most everyone on here is aware. Windows 10 will be the same OS no matter what device it is running on(PC,Tablet,Phone).

I was curious, looked around couldn't find it, so thought I'd drop the question here.

Is the ubuntu OS the same version across Phones, Tablets, and PCs?

Comment: depends on how you define an OS - kernel or kernel + packages.

Comment: "Windows 10 will be the same OS" ehm they want you to believe that ;) Ubuntu will look the same from the outside and we are likely to have the same tools (like click/snappy packages for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Windows 10 for PC and Windows 10 for phones are separate. They share appearance, apps and even name, but you cannot install Windows 10 for PC on a phone or vice versa.

The same applies to Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu touch - you can run the same apps on both platforms,they share kernel, but they are intended for different devices.

Comment: I would upvote but my reputation is too low. Could you cite your sources please?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-messaging-file-explorer - Here two separate versions for PC and for Phone, thus they are not the same.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile

Comment: From what I understood, you will be able to run normal desktop programs (like GIMP and LibreOffice) in Ubuntu Touch. You will also be able to connect the phone to a monitor, or a keyboard to a tablet, and it will "transform" itself into a computer (with a normal desktop on the screen). Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Touch will be very alike, it seems. As for Windows 10, it seems that "one OS for all devices" was all marketing, and you won't be able to run normal desktop programs in phones and small tablets (which is disappointing). This is from what I understood, I may be wrong.